# Organize index of form fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I'm trying to think of a function that helps me organize the custom positioning of fields within a form structure, but I'm not succeeding. If anyone has any ideas, I would be grateful.

This sandbox represents fields in a form that are of the types "Text," "Numeric," "Date," "Time," "uniqueSelection," "multipleSelection," "uniqueSelection," "refUniqueSelection," "refMultipleSelection," and lastly, "refLookup." It is similar to Excel's vLookup the key in object `index` represente position in form.

[codesandbox project link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-gauss-nq3h52)

Visual presentantion of main form and "Carros" and linked form "Completo" in lookup field.

[image: All fields of form]
[image: Lookup field structure]

We have some important conditions:

> item.fieldtype === "refLookup" represents lookup fields within the
> form. item.isReadOnly === true represents child fields of lookup
> fields.

> item.isDeleted === true represents fields that have been deleted from
> the form, but we need to keep them because there may be data in these
> columns that need to be displayed in the table. A significant issue
> here is that when a field is deleted and a new field is created, it
> repeats the same index within the form because it's considered
> available for use again.

> item.fieldtype !== "refLookup" && item.isReadOnly === undefined &&
> item.isDeleted === undefined represents other active fields that are
> neither lookup fields nor children of any other lookup field.

How could I organize the fields in a way that resembles the original form structure, with child fields appearing below their parent fields?